# How make sqlite with entity framework "embedded solution"

Tags: sqlite, embedded-database, .net

I write program on C# and want store any data in database. I want use a database that not required any additional installation on client machine.
I choose SQLite and Entity framework.
I write simple test project that open db and write any rows only to check for all works fine.
For System.data.Sqlite in project references set - copy to output folder, compile and run him on client machine - and get exception:

```
System.ArgumentException
"The specified store provider cannot be found in the configuration, or is not valid."
```

I'm try add provider settings in config file as there:

```
<system.data>
<DbProviderFactories>     
  <remove invariant="System.Data.SQLite"/>
  <add name="SQLite Data Provider" invariant="System.Data.SQLite" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for SQLite" type="System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteFactory, System.Data.SQLite"/>
</DbProviderFactories>
```

And get following error:

```
System.Data.ProviderIncompatibleException
A null was returned after calling the 'GetService' method on a store provider instance of type 'System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteFactory'. The store provider might not be functioning correctly.
```

What i do wrong? It is possible to use sqlite  + entity framework without any additional installation but .net 4.0. 
I use windows 7 64x with installed net 4.0 on my machine and windows 7 32x with installed net 4.0 in client machine
I will be glad for any help